# Should i upgrade to 16.04 from 15.10.. Probably problem with amd graphics

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5730 and use a external monitor 
instead original. I always have problem after updates with good working with this solutions. Often i must reinstall system because i have to black screen or something light that. Now in 15.10 works, should i upgrade ? I read some times ago amd not support 16.04, now it's better ?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 is not supported any more. Questions regarding this version are off-topic here. AMD adapters are supported in 16.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 check AU chat. We are supporting 15.10 until tomorrow. Also, I don't think this question is about 15.10; it's about upgrading, which is on-topic.

Comment: I did not VTC. But it is opinion based anyway.

Comment: @Pilot6 I never claimed you did. I was just responding to your comment, and we accept this type of question a lot ("Should I upgrade?"). At least, I've never seen it closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that AMD isn't supported in 16.04, it's just that there are no proprietary drivers for AMD in 16.04. This basically means almost all games are out of the question, but most other things, including videos, should be fine.

If 15.10 is working for you, you have a difficult decision.

15.10 has reached its end-of-life date *today*, meaning we at Ask Ubuntu will no longer support you if you have any problems. You will also not get any security updates, as the default repositories for EOL releases are frozen.

16.04 is supported, and will be supported until 2021, as it is an LTS (long-term support) release. These happen every two years (12.04 in 2012, 14.04 in 2014, 16.04 in 2016, 18.04 in 2018, etc) and are supported for 5 years after release. However, 16.04 loses any performance you may need from your AMD graphics.

You can either stay with 15.10, with everything working how you want, without any updates or support from us, or you can upgrade to 16.04, which is supported and will receive updates until 2021, risking the performance loss.

If you do stay in 15.10, you can always visit [unix.se] for help, but chances are they will suggest you upgrade to 16.04 to solve any problems.

I can't tell you which to choose, but I can recommend that you take the performance loss and upgrade to 16.04 for the support. And who knows? Maybe a great AMD driver will be released soon.

Comment: Ok thanks you for information, i try to update

Comment: I update and i have a problem. Can't change screen resolution and plug monitor to the laptop. I have only 1024x768

Comment: @Swis ask a new question,